# Issue importing npm package into AdonisJS Controller

Tags: node.js, es6-modules, commonjs

I'm having an issue importing the https://www.npmjs.com/package/lighthouse package into my controller. I get an (error: "Invalid or unexpected token") for the lighthouse import but not the chrome-launcher. I've tried commenting out the lighthouse import and the error goes away so I know it has to do with it. When I tried utilizing ESM instead of CommonJS (i.e: import lighthouse from 'lighthouse';) I got a different (error: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module').

```
const lighthouse = require('lighthouse');
const Launcher = require('chrome-launcher');
const User = use('App/Models/User');
const Mail = use('Mail');
const Company = use('App/Models/Company');
const Project = use('App/Models/Project');
const Task = use('App/Models/Task');
const Database = use('Database');

class ReportingController {
  async getLighthouse({ request }) {
    const { url } = request.only(['url']);
    const chrome = await Launcher.launch({ chromeFlags: ['--headless'] });
    const options = {
      logLevel: 'info',
      output: 'json',
      onlyCategories: ['performance'],
      port: chrome.port,
    };

    const runnerResult = await lighthouse(decodeURIComponent(url), options);
    await chrome.kill();

    return { data: runnerResult };
  }
}

module.exports = ReportingController;
```